# How to delete a word and enter insert mode?

Tags: neovim

I know that by pressing <kbd>s</kbd>, I can delete a character and enter insert mode. How do I do the same for words. Is there an equivalent to <kbd>s</kbd> for deleting a word and entering insert mode?

Answer (score 4):

`s`substitute works on the current character or selection. It doesn't take any movement.

`c`hange however accepts movements -> `ciw`, `ce`, `cw`, `ca"`, `c2t,`, etc.